# Angular Ui Router :stop $state.go to reload controllers but change URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My app uses `$state.go` when switching between tabs and this cause to re-initializes the controllers and scope variable in those controllers get updated and causes memory leaks. Is there a way to stop re-initializing the controllers but change URL on state change?

Example below is routes.js in my app.

```
.state('home', 
{
    abstract    : true,            
    url         : '/home',
    templateUrl : 'scripts/home.html'
})
.state('home.summary', 
{
    url        : '/summary?userId', 
    controller : 'SummaryCtrl',                
    views      : 
    {               
        summary: 
        {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/home/summary.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('home.summary.detail', 
{
    url        : '/detail/:id',
    controller : 'DetailCtrl',                 
    views      : 
    {               
        detail: 
        {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/home/detail.html'
        }
    }
})
```

How to stop reloading DetailCtrl but change URL when going to state home.summary.detail if the DetailCtrl  is already loaded for unique id???

Also tried to $q.reject in resolve of child state, it stops reload of controllers but doesn't change url.

Also tried reloadOnSearch=false it stops reload of controllers but doesn't change url.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `$state.transitionTo`  instead of   `$state.go` .  `$state.go`  calls  `$state.transitionTo`  internally but automatically sets options to  `{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }` . You can call  `$state.transitionTo`  and set  `location: false` . For example:

```
$state.go('.detail', {id: newId})
```

can be replaced by

```
 $state.transitionTo ('.detail', {id: newId}, { location: false, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true })
```

Comment: I think you can just do `$state.go('.detail', {id: newId}, {location: false})`

Comment: I think so, {location: false} is the key option to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can have a abstract controller that contain your memory leak code.
And a abstract controller will not update when url change.

Here is the doc from official github repo

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

look at the Combination part.

here is the plnkr, contacts controller will only call once in this demo
contacts.detail controller will update every time you change state but share the scope with contacts controller
http://plnkr.co/edit/gmtcE2?p=preview

Comment: i have removed the scope variables but still i wouldn't want the child state controllers to reload if they are already loaded.There should be some way to stop reloading controllers but change url on state transistion??

Comment: Also tried to $q.reject in resolve of child state, it stops reload of controllers but doesn't change url.

Also tried reloadOnSearch=false it stops reload of controllers but doesn't change url.